# How to map a Value Object in Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, domain-driven-design

I want map a value object in Entity Framework 4 as in NHibernate where I use Component-Class (Nested in AR). How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that I know of.  The easiest is to use [ComplexType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738472.aspx), which cannot have a key.  The more difficult way is to use a POCO with all setters marked private ([example](http://rogeralsing.com/2009/05/21/entity-framework-4-immutable-value-objects/)) and with a key, which will allow you to persist it to a separate database table.  (Or you can kinda mix to two and do the former with private setters, I suppose.)